# How to place text after VarDecl?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to write a commentary after variable declarations using Clang.

I tried to use getLocEnd function:

```
void PreprocessConsumer::WriteId(clang::VarDecl *vd)
{
    auto location = vd->getLocEnd();

    _rewriter.InsertTextAfterToken(location, "//My label");
    _rewriter.overwriteChangedFiles();
}
```

For this input

```
void f (int n)
    {
        float x[10];
    }
```

it places a comment before semicolon:

```
void f (int n)
    {
        float x[10]//My label;
    }
```

But I want to make Clang write a comment after semicolon as following:

```
void f (int n)
    {
        float x[10];//My label
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a getLocEnd from parent clang::Stmt.